# I'm getting parse error on input `->'

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing

I'm trying to run the following code and it is giving me parse error at `->`

```
{- Make sure you have the hxt, url and http packages:
        cabal install hxt
        cabal install url
        cabal install http
        cabal install hxt-curl -}

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI

weatherDataURL = "http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KAGC.xml"

retrieveWeatherData = do
  case parseURI weatherDataURL of
    Nothing  -> ioError . userError $ "Invalid URL"
    Just uri -> get uri
 {- | Download a URL.  (Left errorMessage) if an error, (Right doc) if success. -}
get uri = do
  eresp <- simpleHTTP (Request uri GET [] "")
  case eresp of
    Left _    -> ioError . userError $ "Failed to get " ++ show uri
    Right res -> return $ rspBody res

    {-readString :: Attributes -> String -> IOStateArrow s b XmlTreeSource read a document
    that is stored in a normal Haskell String the same function as readDocument, but the
    parameter forms the input. All options available for readDocument are applicable for
    readString. -}


parseXML doc = readString [ withValidate no --turn off the validation step.
                          , withRemoveWS yes ---- throw away formatting WS
                          ] doc

data Weather = Weather
  { location, observationTime,
    summary, windDirection :: String,

    temperature, humidity,
    dewpoint,
    pressure, windSpeed,
    visibility             :: Float }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag) -- Selecting all "top level" tag in XML document
text = getChildren >>> getText
textAtTag tag = atTag tag >>> text

getWeather = atTag "current_observation" >>>
        proc x -> do -- proc (arrow abstraction) except that it constructs an arrow instead of a function.
        loc     <- textAtTag "location"          -< x --  reserved symbol used for building commands from an expression of arrow type and an expression to be fed as input to that arrow
        obsTime <- textAtTag "observation_time"  -< x
        summ    <- textAtTag "weather"           -< x
        windDir <- textAtTag "wind_dir"          -< x
        temp    <- textAtTag "temp_c"            -< x
        humi    <- textAtTag "relative_humidity" -< x
        wind    <- textAtTag "wind_mph"          -< x
        pres    <- textAtTag "pressure_mb"       -< x
        dew     <- textAtTag "dewpoint_c"        -< x
        vis     <- textAtTag "visibility_mi"     -< x
    returnA -< Weather
      { location        = loc,
        observationTime = obsTime,
        summary         = summ,
        windDirection   = windDir,
        temperature     = read temp,
        humidity        = read humi,
        windSpeed       = read wind * 1.61,
        pressure        = read pres,
        dewpoint        = read dew,
        visibility      = read vis * 1.61 }

-- GHCi test:
-- Main> retrieveWeatherData >>= \ doc -> runX (parseXML doc >>> getWeather)

main = do
  doc    <- retrieveWeatherData
  xml    <- return $ parseXML doc
  result <- runX (xml >>> getWeather)
  case result of
    []  -> putStrLn "Unable to parse weather data."
    w:_ -> print w
```

Comment: It would be much easier for us if you showed just the part with the syntax error instead of the whole file.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing<sup>1</sup> that your parse error is on this line:

```
proc x -> do
```

If so, that means you haven't told your friendly neighborhood Haskell compiler that you want it to support arrow syntax. You can do that by putting this at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> But in the future, please tell us so we don't *have* to guess.